# Using 'pipenv run' can I run a script outside of the project folder?

Tags: python, pip, scripting, virtualenv, pipenv

In my project folder, which I initiated `pipenv shell`. When in that folder and not in the pipenv virtual enviroment. I can use the command `pipenv run script.py` and it works. However, when I change directory and move outside that project folder like so `pipenv run projectfolder/script.py` it fails with module error. Is there a way to run this script outside of the project folder?

Comment: Just activate your venv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either activate your virtual environment using `pipenv shell` and then run your script like normal, e.g. `python script.py` from within your project directory or `python projectfolder/script.py`.

Or if you are intent on using `pipenv run`, you can use the [`PIPFILE`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.Setting.PIPENV_PIPFILE) setting to set the path to your `Pipfile`. For example, `PIPENV_PIPFILE=projectfolder/Pipfile pipenv run python projectfolder/script.py`.

Comment: For the second part. I was setting the environment variables `PIPENV_PIPFILE` inside the .env file; no good. However, when I ran it straight from the command line, it worked. Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: The values inside your `.env` will only be used by Pipenv if it knows where your `Pipfile` is.